# Problem dealing with copied MySQL data directory

Tags: mysql

I just copied original DB directory in the `/MYSQL/data` folder.

```
cp -pr ORG_DB COPY_DB
```

After that, I can see copied DB name has `#mysql50#DBname`.

How can I switch it to normal Database data?

I'm using mysql-5.2.0-falcon-alpha on CENTOS Linux.

Comment: 5.2.0?  *Falcon*!?  My friend, you have a relic on your hands there.  Once this is all resolved, I highly suggest moving up to 5.5.  Now, did you copy the `data` directory when MySQL was running?

Comment: I did copy data directory while mysqld running.

Comment: It is very likely, then, that what you are seeing is data corruption caused by that.  If you need to make a snapshot of the MySQL data directory *while MySQL is running*, you can only effectively do so using certain techniques, and `cp` isn't one of them.  Can you shut down MySQL and try again?

Answer (score -2):

have you tried PHPMyAdmin ?
it's free !

Comment: Not all of us with MySQL installations also have PHP installations.

Comment: I'm using it already. on the Phpadmin, it looks same.. #mysql50#Dbname. Is it no problem if it looks like that?

Comment: you can try renaming the database from PHPMyAdmin !